# How to use jsonify on a query response?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

Using flask-restful, and having a database which stores, related to places, the name, hour of visit, hour of exit, and date of visit, I have this query:

```
query = conn.execute("select * from geo_example where     init_hour='%d'"%hour_of_visit)
```

How do I use the jsonify function instead of doing it manually like this:

```
result = {'inital_hour': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in     query.cursor]}
```

Comment: I'd start with [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) libraries to abstract database functionality. You're working at a very low level (raw SQL), which is a pain, and seems unnecessary here. Moreover, it's hard to tell what your query outputs right now, but assuming you created a list you want to return from your route, a simple `return jsonify(result={'initial_hour':MyList})` should work fine.

Comment: I'm simply returning that result, with the output like

{
    "inital_hour": [
        {
            "Date": "2016-01-10", 
            "End_Hour": 900, 
            "Init_Hour": 1800, 
            "Name": "HOME"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: the `return jsonify(..)` i've posted above should work for you then. What is failing, if anything?

Comment: And for what I am trying to achieve here, raw SQL makes ir easier for me. Maybe in the future I'll use other libraries.

Comment: I've written this

    `query = conn.execute("select * from geo_example")
        MyList = list (i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall())
        return jsonify ({'places':MyList})`

It works wonderfully. Many thanks!